# What is wrong with my syntax using sep() function?

Tags: python

can someone explain to me why my syntax is wrong??? it is making me frustrated!

#### python

```
city=(input('enter your city: '))
state=(input('enter your state: '))
total=(city, state, sep=' ')
print(total)
```

Comment: `sep` is a parameter to the print() function. Did you mean to call print, somehow? Maybe `print(city, state, sep=' ')`?

Comment: sep isn't a function. In fact in that line you don't call any function at all! So I don't understand what you expect it to do.

Comment: I think @jarmod is correct- change line 3 to
print (city, state, sep=' ')  but keep in mind that the sep is a space by default

Comment: `total=(city, state, sep=' ')` is invalid syntax. Python is interpreting the left hand side as a tuple, but you are making an assignment inside the tuple, which is not allowed. My guess is that you wanted to do `print(city, state, sep=" ")`. In this case, `sep` is interpreted as an argument passed to the print function.

Answer (score 0):

In python functions are used by calling them. Just as you did in the title. Sep is not a function and even if it was it would not work in the way you wrote it.

In python you create a function by defining it.

```
def my_function():
    pass
```

and function are used by calling them.

```
my_function()
```

if a function takes parameters it should be included in the definition.

```
def my_function(a,b):
    pass
```

and this would be used as such

```
my_function(1,2)
```

What you wrote would not call even if `sep` was a python function but it is not a python function.

```
total=(city, state, sep=' ')
```

sep is a print function argument so what you are trying to do probably should look like this but you can't assing the return value of print to total because it will return None

```
print(city, state, sep=' ')
```

If you only want to do some string formatting f string would be way better and powerful. you can write

```
total = f'{city}  {state}'
```